# Failed Install Latest Postgres (11.1) in Linux Mint 17.3 (rosa)

Tags: linux, postgresql

I have problem while installation `postresql-11` in `Linux Mint 17.3`, with environment:

```
clutax@clutax:/home/clutax > sudo lsb_release -a
[sudo] password for clutax: 
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: LinuxMint
Description:    Linux Mint 17.3 Rosa
Release:        17.3
Codename:       rosa


clutax@clutax:/home/clutax > sudo aptitude install postgresql-11
    The following NEW packages will be installed:
      libpq5{ab} postgresql-11{b} postgresql-client-11{a} 
    The following packages are RECOMMENDED but will NOT be installed:
      sysstat 
    0 packages upgraded, 3 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    Need to get 15,4 MB of archives. After unpacking 51,8 MB will be used.
    The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     postgresql-11 : Depends: libicu55 (>= 55.1-1~) which is a virtual package.
                     Depends: libllvm6.0 (>= 1:6.0~svn298832-1~) which is a virtual package.
                     Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3) but 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.27 is installed.
                     Depends: libstdc++6 (>= 5.2) but 4.8.4-2ubuntu1~14.04.4 is installed.
                     Depends: libsystemd0 which is a virtual package.
     libpq5 : Depends: libssl1.0.0 (>= 1.0.2~beta3) but 1.0.1f-1ubuntu2.27 is installed.
    The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

         Keep the following packages at their current version:
    1)     libpq5 [Not Installed]                             
    2)     postgresql-11 [Not Installed]                      
    3)     postgresql-client-11 [Not Installed]               


    Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] Y
    No packages will be installed, upgraded, or removed.
    0 packages upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
    Need to get 0 B of archives. After unpacking 0 B will be used.

    clutax@clutax:/home/clutax > ^C
```

How I can solve the problems?

Answer (score 0):

check the apt repository of your linux-mint, if it's Bionic, Xenial or Trusty and add the correct repo. else you will continue to get this error.

eg. Bionic:

```
$ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ bionic-pgdg main" > \ 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/postgresql.list'
```

Xenial:

```
    $ sudo sh -c 'echo "deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ xenial-pgdg main" > \ 
/etc/apt/sources.list.d/postgresql.list'
```

then add the package repository key:

```
wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -
```

and continue with the rest of the process update and install.